# React + Webpack - Invariant Violation Error in simple Hello World component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So far I have managed to finally figure out how to configure my webpack.config.js file to handle jsx files. here it is:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.jsx"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader", query: {presets: ['react', 'es2015']}}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

And what I am trying to do is render a very simple react component with a react-bootstrap button:

HelloWorld.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      spanish: false
    }
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({spanish: true});
  },
  render: function() {
    const text = this.state.spanish ? 'Hola Mundo!' : 'Hello World';
    const buttonText = this.state.spanish ? 'Click Para Cambiar a Inglés' : 'Click to Swith To Spanish';
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{text}</h1>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>{buttonText}</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

And here is the entry point for the application:

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HelloWorld } from './components/HelloWorld';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "soundcloud-player",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Now I have two issues happening here, and I have no clue why it's happening:

1. When I go to localhost:8080, I get an invariant violation error and a warning:

   index_bundle.jsx:1300 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

   Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
2. When I remove the 'resolve' part of my webpack.config.js, all of a sudden the project is unable to find my ./components/HelloWorld component and throws a lot of errors

For the first issue, I've tried using {} when importing components, but to no avail. The second issue is a mystery to me, as I believe it should fetch all jsx files because i've specified that in the 'test' part of my loaders. Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my project? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're getting confused about imports. `export default` = `import ClassName` (**without braces**). `export class ...` = `import {ClassName}` (**with braces**, if it is **not default**).

Comment: @Aurora0001 Wow... I feel so dumb. I just changed import { HelloWorld } in my index.jsx file and now I got it working. Thanks! Any idea about issue #2 regarding the resolve in my webpack.config.js?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would want to remove the `resolve` section. By doing that, you're telling Webpack, 'only try to load your default extensions (`["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]`, [as the docs specify](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions)). You would have to explicitly specify the extension of jsx files in your imports if you removed the `resolve` section.

Comment: @Aurora0001 It was just a curiosity on my part. I'm still learning the ropes, so just trying to take out/put in things to see what happens. Anyway, Thanks a lot, and I'll accept your answer if you publish it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a bit confused about the different import types in ES6. When you `export default` a class or variable, you must import it without using braces. For example:

**A.js**

```
class X {

}

export default X;
```

**B.js**

```
import X from 'A.js';
```

On the other hand, if you export something without setting it as default, you must use the braces (e.g. `import { X } from 'A.js';`, if I hadn't set it as a default export).

To understand why this works, it helps to see what happens in ES5 syntax. A default export essentially translates to this:

```
module.exports = MyExportedClass;
```

Then, when you import it, `import MyExportedClass from 'A.js';` translates to:

```
var MyExportedClass = require('A.js');
```

Non-default exports are actually named properties in an object:

```
export class X {

};
```

Translates to:

```
module.exports = {
    X: /* translated class */
}
```

As for your second issue, removing the `resolve` line will reset it to the default values: `["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]`. This is specified in the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions).

By removing `.jsx` from the recognised extensions, Webpack will not look for `.jsx` files unless you explicitly include the extension.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you import the wrong class in the index.jsx.
Either this must be changed:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import { HelloWorld } from './components/HelloWorld';
//to
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

or you have to change the export in the HelloWorld.jsx.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      spanish: false
    }
  },
  handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({spanish: true});
  },
  render: function() {
    const text = this.state.spanish ? 'Hola Mundo!' : 'Hello World';
    const buttonText = this.state.spanish ? 'Click Para Cambiar a Inglés' : 'Click to Swith To Spanish';
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{text}</h1>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>{buttonText}</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

export {
    HelloWorld
}
```

I think the first approach is the cleaner.